# Can't get window after install of Debian Bookworm

Tags: linux, debian, xorg, kde

I did a fresh install of Debian Bookworm on one of my servers, but now I can't get a KDE window to come up under XDM.  In order to maintain consistency between my servers - not for any personal reasons - I set up the system with KDE and the KDM.  This setup is working fine on all my other servers, and when I attempt to login from the console it works, but when I attempt to login via XDMCP, KDM says the login is successful, but then just brings up a black screen.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Clean Debian Bookworm install on an AMD-64 system from an SSD boot disk.
XDMCP Login: "C:\Program Files\Xming\Xming.exe" :1 -clipboard -query backup

Using SSH, I can get xclock, etc to bring up a window on display 0 of the windows machine.